# How to improve persistence USB speed?

Tags: live-usb, persistence

As I am not able to carry my laptop, so I carry a persistent installation of Ubuntu on my USB 2.0 16GB pendrive for my linux class.

The problem I face is that when I use Live mode it is fast enough to use Ubuntu. But some command like `chmod`, `chown` etc. don't work. Hence I force to use persistence live mode. But speed in the persistence mode is so slow that even Firefox is not opening.

I have tried to use a lightweight distro like Lubuntu, but there is no big difference.

I just want my browser and other tools to work properly. I am creating persistence USB via `mkusb`.

Comment: The type of pendrive is USB 2 16GB storage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the best solution is to get a **really fast USB 3 pendrive.** Often the flash memory hardware is limiting the speed, so you should search for a pendrive with documented high performance on both reading and writing. See the following link and links from it,

[Installation/FromUSBStick - Notes about speed | Ubuntu Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Notes_about_speed)

---

I use Sandisk Extreme pendrives for this purpose, and I make persistent live systems in them with **[mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)**. Please search for current information via the internet in order to find alternative pendrives and methods.

You should also **avoid installing too many program packages** into the persistent live system. And you **must *not* upgrade the whole system**. This will make the system slow, and it might even make the system fail, because it will be choked with too much reading from the 'casper-rw' partition or file.

Comment: You are welcome and good luck :-)

Comment: **Better to make a full install on separate USB.** That way you can have all your drivers, configs, updates, optimizations, etc done and saved for all subsequent sessions. I suppose using a superfast USB is desirable (if affordable) but not essential for this. But always have **plenty of swap space** reserved on your full installation USB.

Comment: @Trunk, In many cases, yes, it is better to make a full install on separate USB, but there are cases when I would prefer a persistent live drive. I agree also with your comments on USB speed and swap space. And I would add, that plenty of RAM helps a lot. After all, swapping is slow even in an SSD (*very* slow and causes wear in a simple (non-SSD) USB drive).

Comment: In my experience - and I am only a serious Ubuntuist for < 1 year - a live image USB is vital for disk repair and restoring off a backup. Maybe it's better to have this live drive preconfigured and holding just those apps (e.g. Timeshift, disk utilities, system utilities, etc) that such emergencies demands. So that's one area of benefit for a live persistent USB image. One of those high-speed USBs is also desirable for fast repair. Please share other situations you know of for live persistent USBs. But Aravind's situation seemed to me more a case for a full install.

Comment: @Trunk, During the almost 4 years since this question was asked some things have changed in favor of installed systems versus persistent live systems. So today I can agree with you about what would be the best system for Aravind. - Generally, a persistent live drive can also be used as your portable computer system when travelling, because it is more likely to work in various computers than an installed system. Furthermore, it causes less wear on the USB memory cells and needs less drive space than a corresponding installed system.

Comment: I have to amend my views on this. I have found that after a while of using a full install on a USB it tends to drag and eventually seize. No doubt the continuous work of the OS is too much for the slow and more fragile USB memory. So I cannot advocate anything other than a Live OS Installer on a USB. For a persistent/permanent install it's far better to get a cheap external hard drive and install your op system there. If there is space partition it so you have backup space too. Some external HDs are very small and connect via a USB port. The OS installation time will also be much shorter.

Comment: @Trunk, I think that today an SSD is a better alternative than a HDD for an external operating system. SSDs were never sensitive to mechanical shock, and today the memory cells are very resistent to wear, and the price is low. A standard SATA-SSD plus a USB3 to SATA adpater is a lost cast alternative. If you want it small there are M2-SSDs in boxes, but they are more expensive (I think).